# Getting empty a char that needs to be empty at the beginning of every iteration of a loop function

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I created a char called `aux` that I need just as a variable in which to process the sufixes of the `a`char and to check if these sufixes are prefixes of the `b` char. So, I'm trying to get this `aux` char overwriten at every iteration (or if I can say, to get it "empty" and ready for the next iteration when the program will write in it the characters from the iteration`i+1`)so that i don't need a `aux` of a large size and i really don't want to risk to have in`aux` characters from the previous iteration. So, how do I get it empty, or how do I overwrite the char, especially if in the`i+k` iteration the program would send less characters than in the previous iteration, so it can't not really overwrite because there are less charaters and we could end up with characters from 2 iterations in `aux`. Here are the lines where i tried to do this. `min` is the minimum between `strlen(a)` and `strlen(b)` and `na` is `strlen(a)`.The algorithm is working properly but just if I declare a large physical dimension for `aux` ... like `aux[100]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{   char a[31], b[31], aux[31];
    unsigned int i, na, nb, min;

    na = strlen(a);
    nb = strlen(b);

    if (na < nb)
        min = na;
    else
        min = nb;


    cout << "Define a:";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Define b:";
    cin >> b;
    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < min;i++)
    {   aux[0] = '\0';
        strcpy_s(aux, a + (na - i - 1));
        if (strstr(b, aux) == b)
            cout << aux << " "; 
    }

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: just declare it in the loop body

Comment: I suggest you use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) if you are doing string manipulation.

Comment: You're calling it a `char` a few times but you really mean a char-array, no?

Comment: probably ... Example: Lets say the word in `a` is "software". In the first iteration, the program should write in `aux` "e". After the program runs through the `if` and it displays or not, I would like to get `aux` empty because now the program should write in `aux` "re", in the next iteration "are", in the next "ware" ... and so on ... and if I can't overwrite, I would need a very large `aux`, and I don't need the characters from the previous iteration, so there is no reason to keep them.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding your question, it'd be useful if you posted more of your code - the definition of `a,b,aux, na, min`, etc. As for what I think your code tries to do, you don't need to "empty" `aux`, `strcpy` will write the terminating null, and `strstr` only compares up to the first null. I tried it and it seems to work. You have to ensure `aux` is at least as large as `a`.

Comment: Ramon, I posted the full algorithm. `aux` has the same size as `a` and I get a buffer error ... this probably means that `aux` is not reseted. And if it's not reseted by the code `aux[0]='\0'`, it's not enough to have the same size of `a` it has to be = na*(na+1)/2

Comment: Ah, there is your problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your `aux`'s first element to `\0` or use `memset(aux, 0, sizeof(aux))`

EDIT:

```
aux[0] = '\0';
```

puts the end sign to the start of the string, making it empty. So, if you copy to this (empty) string again, the copied data will override the previously written data, making your memory handling more efficient, which is the exact goal of this question.

Comment: how could I set the first element to be `'\0'` (NULL element) ? .... I don't want to use special fuctions.... just basic strings functions because I haven't reached this chapter in the learning process but if I have to solve this with what I learned, it means that it should be solvable in easier ways. I hope I made myself understood

Comment: @Skyp89, you can set it like this: aux[0] = '\0'; I believe this is the correct answer. I will edit it to improve it slightly, but Z0133 is basically right.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, the variable `aux` must be big enough to contain the whole of the variable pointed at by `a` so if you've declared that to be, for instance, `char a[50];` then you also need `char aux[50];`, it cannot be smaller...
On the other hand, to reset `aux` at each iteration simply write `aux[0] = '\0';` as the first line inside the loop...

Comment: no, it's not enough if I have have 50 characters in `a` to have `char aux[50]`.If I can't reset `aux` I would probably need aux to have exactly : 1+2+3+4+5+ ... + 50 characters ... so `aux` would have to have the physical capacity of (50*51)/2=1275 characters ..

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing `na` and `nb` before `a` and `b` are filled with input, so you'll get a random size from `strlen`. Give it a try, you'll see. As such, your algorithms break.

Try moving it below the input.

```
cout << "Define a:";
cin >> a;
cout << "Define b:";
cin >> b;
cout << endl;

na = strlen(a);
nb = strlen(b);

if (na < nb)
    min = na;
else
    min = nb;
```

I've tried it with this order and it works as expected, without the need to `aux[0] = '\0';`

Comment: Man, I'm happy that you asked me to put the full code ... this was the mistake and I was looking only in the loop because i thought there is the mstake. You are right ... this was the mistake ... I did some CTR+X and CTRL+V in the code and maybe that's how it got there. Now it works with `aux` having the size of `a` +1!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. When debugging, always validate your assumptions about your variables. Also note that you really don't need to "empty" aux, `strcpy` and `strstr` work with null termination, so as far as they are concerned, `aux` is only as long as the first terminating '\0', which `strcpy` sets appropriately.

Comment: You are right, I can see now that I don't need in this example to set the null value at the begining of `aux`. It works just fine just having `aux` with the same size like `a`. I don't think I understood what you said about the null termination of `strcpy_s` and `strstr` .. But ... when `strcpy_s` is runing the second time, it copies at the end of what it wrote the first time, or it writes from `aux[0]` because that's just the way  `strcpy_s` works ?

Comment: It starts copying to `aux[0]` because that is the value you passed to it. `aux` is a `char*` pointing to the first element of the array, so that's where it starts copying to, always. You could send a different location - like you do with the source `a + (na - i + 1)` - but why would you. This is the signature for the function `char *strcpy( char *dest, const char *src );`, you can see that it takes `char*`.